# Angular directive template for dynamic youtube popup

Tags: angular, angular-directive

I want to create directive `youtube-video-popup.directive.html` that will listen to clicks on the element and will create popup from template dynamically.
E.g. I want this html and all methods to be embed in directive so I can just add functionality like this`<a youtubeVideoPopup="aFLEAmssDfax"></a>` and pass `videoId` to generated popup e.g.:

```
<div preventBodyScroll class="modal-window modal-window--dark modal-window--no-padding">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="modal-window__close" (click)="closeVideoPopup()"></a>

    <div class='embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9'>
        <iframe id="ytplayer" type="text/html" [src]="videoId" frameborder="0" allowfdivlscreen></iframe>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="modal-backdrop" (click)="toggleVideoPopup()"></div>
```

I dont want this to be component as it will require some extra coding including `(click)` handlers each time - I have a lot of various elements that can trigger youtube video popup with different layouts and styles.

Can anyone suggest a direction to move? Is it possible to achieve this with Angular 5+? I started from creating template but `@Directive` does not even accept `templateUrl` as a param.

---

one of the possible solutions I see for this particular youtube-popup case is to use `<youtube-popup-component>` directly in `app.component.html` and pass id to the component through the `directive -> service -> component` chain and show popup based on that ad, assuming only one youtube popup can be on the page at once

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can for example look at this repository https://github.com/pleerock/ngx-tooltip/tree/master/src. There you have some example of directive that is appending dynamically created component to component with applied [tooltip]. Basically the most important thing to do is to inject `ViewContainerRef` and `ComponentFactoryResolver` to your directive, from there you can build some component and attach it to DOM.

Comment: sounds like a plan, will check this out, ty!